# Logitech webcam mic/combo doesn't work, only webcam no mic

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, webcam, microphone, logitech

After searching the internet for 100+ hours, I decided to ask here. I've literally gone through 10 pages of google search of the title. Nothing works. I upgraded the kernel and seems like it worked for a couple of days but then I had to reboot and poof, it went again. can I have a permanent fix for this?

Logitech C270 webcam/mic combo

Screenshots of some stuff I tried:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It isn't detected in anything unless I restart on which also there is a very low chance it will work
I also tried plugging in the webcam after the system is on

NOTHING works! I don't want to switch back to windows as then I cant do much dev stuff. Also please give a temp fix if not permanent as I have classes in a few hrs :)

Comment: PS: in the images it shows that I have a mic, it is my headset mic and makes a TON of static noise. please ignore that. The point is that my webcam's mic isnt there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! It is a temp-fix tho! still looking for answeres:

For future ppl with the same issue: You have to build the linux kernel by urself. I Used this guide: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

:)

Edit: I have plugged in a old usb condenser mic, which gets detected on boot, but not my webcam's. trick is to replug the webcam and voila, it is detected! i think the usb mic is forcing `snd_usb_audio` to start and thus loading my webcam later

Comment: I'm so tired of this standard Linux experience like "Problem: USB mic doesn't work. Solution: You have to build the Linux kernel by yourself." :'(